# Simple Arduino Button LED code

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, led

I created this project so that when I push and hold the pushbutton down, it will blink the three LEDs on my breadboard. The problem with this is as soon as I push it down once, the LEDs never stop blinking, even if I let go of the button. I'm pretty sure the problem is that the program is only reading the button state once and then continuing on to the rest of the program. Is there a way to update the button every tenth of a second? Or if there is another way to fix it, please feel free to respond. Here's my code(not the prettiest I know):

```
//Assigns button to digital pin 4
int buttonPin = 4;

void setup() {
//sets pins 1-3 as output pins
for (int ledPin= 1; ledPin <= 3; ledPin++) {
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}
//sets the button pin as a button
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  //puts button state into variable "button"
  int button = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //while button is pushed, blink leds in order
  while (button == LOW) {
    for (int ledPin = 1; ledPin <= 3; ledPin++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }
  //while button is not pushed, turn off leds
  while (button == HIGH) {
  for (int ledPin = 1; ledPin <= 3; ledPin++) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as you said, you're only reading the button state at the beginning of your loop then entering a while that can't exit because `button` is never updated again. Since the `loop()` function runs as long as the Arduino is running (after `setup()`, of course), you can update your code to look like this:

```
void loop() {
  //puts button state into variable "button"
  int button = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  //if button is pushed, blink leds in order
  if (button == LOW) {
    for (int ledPin = 1; ledPin <= 3; ledPin++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }else if (button == HIGH) { //if button is not pushed, turn off leds
    for (int ledPin = 1; ledPin <= 3; ledPin++) {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

What this will do is check the button's state, then if it's pressed flash the LEDs, otherwise set them all to off. You don't need the while loops since `loop()` will run again as soon as it finishes, so you will get continuous response to your actions. Alternatively, if you want to make it so that releasing the button during a flash cycle stops it, you can add something like this to the first for loop:

```
button = digitalRead(buttonPin);
if(button == HIGH) break;
```

What that will do is check the button again while the LEDs are being flashed and if the button has been released it will exit the for loop. That being said, since you have a delay in there, it could miss you releasing then re-pressing the button if that happens within the 500ms delay.

Hopefully that helps you!

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped me out. I can't believe i couldn't  figure that one out by myself haha!